# How to generate swagger 2 models for Stripe Java SDK?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, stripe-payments

I'm using `Spring cloud` + `Swagger` to build a SaaS system, which needs `Stripe` SDK to take payment.

The problem is that `Stripe`'s SDK uses `Gson` annotations to shape the JSON serialized models. For example:

```java
package com.stripe.model;

public class Dispute extends ApiResource implements MetadataStore<Dispute>, BalanceTransactionSource {
  @SerializedName("balance_transactions")
  List<BalanceTransaction> balanceTransactions;
}
```

I declare a REST api to return a `Dispute`:

```java
class StripeController {
  @GetMapping("/disputes")
  Dispute getDispute(@RequestParam String id) {
    Dispute dispute = stripeService.getDispute(id);
  }
}
```

I hope this REST api prints `{"balance_transactions":"..."}` rather than `{"balanceTransactions":"..."}`.

At first, I write a `StripeObjectSerializer` to let `Jackson` serialize it as expected in response:

```java
public class StripeObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<StripeObject> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(StripeObject stripeObject, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeRawValue(stripeObject.toJson());
    }
}
```

It basically works!

However, Swagger cannot recognize `StripeObjectSerializer`, it creates models like `{"balanceTransactions":"..."}` with so many extra useless properties, such as `lastResponse`.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe try using `.getRawJsonObject().toString()` ([link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/110ae567c68aa67cfe697a6309d35e3d13c5e419/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/StripeObject.java#L44-L63))to get the raw JSON String of the API response and then using that for what you write out to the serializer, instead of toJson(), I think it would work better.